# Need help for inheriting API in Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, object-oriented-analysis

I have 4 classes like this:

```
 public abstract class AbstractGraphObject()
 {

       public abstract void draw(Graphics gr,int x,int y);
 }

 public class Line extends AbstractGraphObject()
 {

       public void draw(Graphics gr,int x,int y);
 }

 public class Rectangle extends AbstractGraphObject()
 {

       public void draw(Graphics gr,int x,int y);

 }



 public class Circle extends AbstractGraphObject()
 {

     public void draw(Graphics gr,int x,int y);

 }
```

The class Line and Rectangle has been implemented . I'm implementing the class Circle. However, I found an API to draw an ellipse in general.

```
 public class Ellipse()
 {

     public void paint(Graphics gr,int x,int y);

 }
```

However I  am not able to modify code of the existing class Ellipse but still want to reuse this class and implement a Circle following the design above. How do I do this? How can and use OOP in this case?

PS: I have to reuse this Ellipse API. Please don't tell me to define the Circle myself.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Delegate to that method from the `Circle` method?

Comment: can you explain more brief? I'm new to OOP in Java. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the to interface instead of abstract in order to use the same a design above, ans since Java does not support multi inheritance,

so it could be something like this:

```
public interface GraphObjectModel()
{
   public abstract void draw(Graphics gr,int x,int y);
}
```

then your class could use `GraphObjectModel` and `Ellipse` API's

```
public class Circle extends Ellipse implements GraphObjectModel
{
    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics gr,int x,int y){ }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics gr,int x,int y){}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you want:

```
 public class Circle extends AbstractGraphObject()
 {
   private Ellipse eclipse;
   public Circle(Ellipse eclipse){
      this.eclipse = eclipse;
   }

   public void draw(Graphics gr,int x,int y){
      eclipse.paint(gr,x,y);
   }
 }
```

Comment: thank you so much,i think this is the piece of code that i want:)

Answer (score 0):

There is no multiple inheritance in Java so `Circle` can only extend `Ellipse` or `AbstractGraphObject`.

If you really want to follow that design you may create a delegate `Circle` class that wraps a `Ellipse` object. That means that it is a `Circle` and an `AbstractGraphObject`, not an `Ellipse` but it internally uses an `Ellipse` to be drawn.

I rather another option changing the design. You change your design so it is based on a new `GraphObject` interface instead of a `AbstractGraphObject` abstract class. All your Graph classes will implement it. There is no superclass restriction any more so `Circle` may extend `Ellipse` in this case. For the rest of `GraphObject` they may optionally extend a **helper** `AbstractGraphObject` base class if that helps you in any way.